# View PDF in Internet Explorer with preventing user to download or print

Tags: object, pdf, internet-explorer, viewer

I want to show the PDF in Internet Explorer in a way that it isn't downloaded or printable by the user.

Trying to show the PDF in iframe in Internet Explorer. Want to hide the toolbar shown with download and print functionality. If I anyhow hide the toolbar, the PDF still can be printed by right clicking on it and print option is shown. Let me know the solution to prevent user from downloading and printing the PDF file.

Just allow the user to view the PDF and cannot download or print it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any options available in internet Explorer or in that add on which shows the PDF file in Internet Explorer to prevent user from downloading or printing the PDF files.

If you are displaying the PDF file than users have many options to download or print it.

User can take a snapshot or use print screen or simply copy the text from your PDF.

So you cannot block all the options and there is no any built in option for this.

what you can do is display your PDF as an image with your own watermark in it.

So if someone downloads it than also the viewer knows the source of the file and its content.